# display all images in folder without php

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova

I am working on an HTML5 app and I am trying to show all images in a folder using no PHP. I want to pull the files from a local folder on the user's machine since I want the user to be able to save images into this folder and view them in a slideshow without the use of a server.

It seems this is not possible without PHP due to security concerns but I would think with so many web apps and smartphone apps being created out there, there would be a way to do this locally by now without having to use a server...perhaps with CSS, JQuery or fileapi?

Any feedback on if this is possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "pull the files from a local folder" - Reading files from a directory on the server, or the client's machine?

Comment: I woudl like the app to be reading files directly from the client's machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML5 app"?

Comment: A web based/android/ios app written in HTML5 that can be deployed ideally with phonegap.

Comment: You should specify in the question that you're using Phonegap. It's not possible to list local folder contents in "normal" browser-based JavaScript but Phonegap and other app wrappers have specific functions that let you get around browser limitations.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the wrappers having additional features just wasnt sure if I was able to do it without one.

Comment: Use Python instead of PHP if you dislike PHP that much, but personally I think you're making it harder on yourself if that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mvanzyl,
The first thing to clarify is that building a Mobile App means you will most, if not all, of your services on the machine. In the typical Model App model, the remote server is used for storing data and perhaps very intensive computation. So this means, you should plan your Mobile App to do everything on the mobile device.

As for seeing images on Apps, YES you can. And you can write an App to see the images. For those images not directly stored on the App, you must located those images via the [Phonegap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File). That is to say, you have images in your App, that are part of the UI; and other images, such as photographs, that require the File API.

The bonus of using Phonegap is that your UI works like a webpage, so you can dynamically add images, just like you do on most webpages that use Javascript. The biggest difference is the URL. For Android you will use `content://` instead of `http://` or `file://`. Apple has a similar structure, but a different key word (which I don't recall right). To finish, I should say I have not tried to do this. --Jesse